# Visual Studio TypeScript post-compile-on-save event

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

I have a TypeScript project with 'compile on save' option enabled.
I would like to execute external command (executable file) after every time I save a file in my TypeScript project.

How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Compile on save is specific to typescript and not available as a build step. You can do that using external tools e.g combine https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch and https://github.com/grunt-ts/grunt-ts

Answer (score 0):

There is a sample extension for Visual Commander that [runs cppcheck on file save](http://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/extensions.html) (#2) using DTE.Events.DocumentEvents.DocumentSaved. You can easily adapt it to run your executable instead.